# Why does MessageBox be run several times in this code?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in programming and writing codes.
I have a very simple form with 6 buttons.
When I click on every button only the sender's text got Magenta.
But Button3 do a further work and that's opening a "Hello" messageBox.
The problem is when I click on Button3, it shows "hello" string 4 times. Why?
I think and expect it show it just once no more.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Typhok(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x.Equals(sender))
                x.ForeColor = Color.Magenta;
            else
                x.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        b3.Click += new EventHandler(Popup);
    }

    private void Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello!");
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Can anyone explain to me why that original code had that problem?

Comment: when is `Typhok` called? it looks like another event handler. and each time thats called `Popup` will be reregistered.

Answer (score 8):

Register event handler in constructor, not in Typhok method. The final code should look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        b3.Click += new EventHandler(Popup);
    }

    private void Typhok(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x.Equals(sender))
                x.ForeColor = Color.Magenta;
            else
                x.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain *why* this works and *why* the original code produces the observed results.  Events can have multiple handlers assigned to them.  Each call of `... += new EventHandler(Popup)` attaches a new delegate to the handler and all attached delegates are called each time the event fires.  If the handler has been added three times it will fire three times.  The solution is to ensure that the handler is assigned only once.

Comment: @lon md Thanks so much. I can't give thumbs up to your answer.